# RegExp, Remove dots in tags

Tags: c#, regex

I've been searching and searching but just can't find the solution.
I need to remove the dots in the tags of an XML doc with RegExp in c#....

so for example:

```
test <12.34.56>test.test<12.34>
```

should be:

```
test <12346>test.test<1234>
```

So basically removing dots but only in the tags.... any ideas?

Comment: Is there a particular reason you "need to remove ... **with RegExp**" ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
resultString = Regex.Replace(subjectString, @"\.(?=[^<>]*>)", "");
```

replaces a dot with the empty string only if the next following angle bracket is a closing angle bracket.

This is of course brittle since closing angle brackets might occur inside the text between tags, but if you're sure that won't be the case, you should be OK.

**Explanation:**

```
\.      # Match a dot
(?=     # only if the following regex can be matched at the current position:
 [^<>]* #  - zero or more characters except < or >
 >      #  - followed by a >
)       # End of lookahead assertion
```

Comment: Yeah, that worked very well! I'm not sure i fully understand why, but that doesn't matter as long as it works :-)

Comment: @NicolajB: I have added an explanation, hope this helps.

Comment: didn't see the explanation untill now. VERY useful! thx a lot

Answer (score 2):

I would use an xml parser for it

```
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(new StringReader("<root><s123.45><s678.9>aaaa</s678.9></s123.45></root>"));
foreach (var elem in xdoc.Descendants()) 
    elem.Name = elem.Name.LocalName.Replace(".", "");
Console.WriteLine(xdoc);
```

Comment: I have a nasty suspicion that it's going to turn out that what the asker has isn't actually xml at all, but just a string that happens to contain some angle brackets. I could well be wrong of course :)

Comment: Well it's a good point (to just traverse the XML), but as AakashM say it is not really XML..... or said in another way; the ones who gave the doc to me thinks it is XML.... but it is not wellformed :-)